# Showing file selection UI : Integrating Dropbox with OAuth 2

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to create a web page which will allow my user to upload a file to my S3 storage. For choosing the file user can use Google Drive, Dropbox and also local system. Am facing issues while implementing the Dropbox part of this.

Am using [this](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/45/using-oauth-20-with-the-core-api) technique for integration(using core API and OAuth 2).

First when user chooses Dropbox i am opening an HTML page in an IFrame. Here I have an authorize button which will open the authorize endpoint mentioned in the above link. This link shows me X-FRAME-Options error inside the Iframe so i had to open this link as a popup to work.

Is there a way around this? I'd like the authorize URL to open in the same iframe by using location.href.

Also when i open it as a popup, after the user logs in successfully the redirect_uri which i pass i getting opened in the popup. I had to do some unconventional setInterval coding to go around this. Can someone suggest a solution for this as well?

I also tried using CSRF tokens as mentioned in [Smarx's](https://github.com/smarx/othw/tree/master/JavaScript) blog but this also gives me the same error.

EDIT :

@smarx i tried using dropbox.js and it works fine. Stuck at one place
I used the OAuth popup driver and have a button which says sign-in.

First on load i create the client and then the popup driver as below

```
client = new Dropbox.Client({ key: client_id });
client.authDriver(new Dropbox.AuthDriver.Popup({
        receiverUrl: "http://localhost/uploadCare/dbcallback.html"
    });
);
```

And in the call back html i am writing

```
Dropbox.AuthDriver.Popup.oauthReceiver()
```

as mentioned in the docs.
But this does not take me back to the original page and show me the list of files.

I particularly did not understand this part of the explanation
"**To use the popup driver, create a page on your site that contains the receiver code, change the code to reflect the location of dropbox.js on your site, and point the Dropbox.AuthDriver.Popup constructor to it**."

Could you please help me out here.

Comment: What do you mean "But this does not take me back to the original page and show me the list of files."? The original page should just be sitting there the whole time and should still be there after the popup closes.

Comment: Ok. Let me try to explain. I have a login button on my original page on click of which a popup is opened. Once i enter my credentials inside the popup i expect the popup to close and the authentication details to be communcated back to the original page so that i can show the list of files in the original page. Right now what is happening is in the popup after i login the receiverUrl is being loaded but nothing happens in the original page

Comment: In the receiver code, is the call to `oauthReceiver` actually executed? Are there any errors in the browser console? Any chance you can share the actual web page with the issue?

Comment: @smarx i've got it working now and it works perfectly. I actually had a js error in the console due to which it was not working. Thanks a lot :) It works with **Dropbox.AuthDriver.Popup.oauthReceiver()** . Although one small question. The page asks for a permission as well after login is there any way i can byepass that?

Comment: No. You can't access someone's Dropbox account without asking their permission first. But each user should only have to authorize your app once.

Comment: Fair enough. i can live with that :) . The pages to get the  [dropbox-js API](http://coffeedoc.info/github/dropbox/dropbox-js/master/class_index.html) is not loading. Is there some way to get the metadata of the file? Mainly i want the file url. Something similar to **//api.dropbox.com/1/media/auto/file_name** ? **client.readFile** only gets the content. I am sure some API should be there but can't browse the APIs as the URL is not loading

Comment: I *think* the method you're looking for is `metadata` (or `stat`): https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/blob/stable/src/client.coffee#L740. But the URL you mentioned would be for a call to media, which is `makeUrl` in the JS library: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/blob/stable/src/client.coffee#L767.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely can't put dropbox.com into an iframe, for security reasons (e.g. [clickjacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking)).

A few suggestions:

1. Can you just use [the Chooser](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js) for your use case? That would certainly be easier for you and your users.
2. If you can't use the Chooser, is there a reason you're not using [dropbox.js](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js)? It has a popup auth driver that will pretty much just take care of all this for you. The redirect will definitely happen in the same window as auth, so communication between the windows (usually via `localStorage`) is generally necessary. This is already done in dropbox.js.

Comment: Ill try dropbox.js and update the same here. Thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: smarx can you please check the edited question and give your suggestion?